# User icon appears behind Map Marker

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, react-native-maps

My user Icon is currently appearing behind the map marker as shown in the picture. I've tried to add flex:1 but haven't had any luck. It seems to work fine when I use showsUserLocation={true} in android. Is there a way to push the userlocation icon infront of the mapmarker? Have also gone through the options on here but still no luck github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1668

[image: Map Icon appears infront of showUserLocation icon]

```
               <Map
                ref={refMap}
                onPress={onDeselectVenue}
                provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
                customMapStyle={MAP_STYLE}
                showsMyLocationButton={false}
                showsUserLocation={true}
                initialRegion={{
                    latitude: coordinates.latitude,
                    longitude: coordinates.longitude,
                    latitudeDelta: 0.05,
                    longitudeDelta: 0.05,
                }}>
                {
                    state.clubLocations.map((clubLocation) => <ClubMarker key={clubLocation.clubId} inactive={isInactive(clubLocation)} onPress={onSelectLocation(clubLocation)} coordinate={clubLocation.location} />)
                }
            </Map>
```

Comment: This seems to be fixed at https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/issues/1668 Which version are you using ?

Comment: "react-native-maps": "^0.27.1",